# Unable to send SMTP email from Azure App Service using Microsoft 365 Relay via port 25

Tags: c#, azure, email, smtp, office365

We have a Microsoft 365 business account which we want to use in order to send emails from our .NET Core C# Blazor applications that are hosted in Azure (Azure App Service).

We have followed Option 3 of this documentation: [Configure a connector to send mail using Microsoft 365 or Office 365 SMTP relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#option-3-configure-a-connector-to-send-mail-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365-smtp-relay) in order to set up an external relay in the Exchange of our 365 account.

When our App Service Plan is set to the free tier, we are able to successfully send emails from our Blazor application in Azure from an email address that uses our domain (noreply@ourcompany.com) to an external Gmail address, thus proving that the relay is working.

However, once we upgrade the App Service Plan to a paid tier (I have tried Basic B1 and Standard S1), the emails fail to send, giving the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server
> response was: 5.7.64 TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied
> [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate]

When I change the App Service Plan back to the free tier...it works again. Has anyone else encountered this, or may know why emails won't send from a paid Azure App Service Plan, but do send from a free Azure App Service Plan?

In our Blazor application, I have a button that calls the following method:

```
private async Task SendEmail()
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress("someemailaddress@ourcompany.com"),
        Subject = "365 Test",
        Body = "Hello, this is a test."
    };

    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("someexternalemail@gmail.com"));

    await EmailService.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

Which calls our email service:

```
public interface ITestEmailService
{
    Task SendAsync(MailMessage mailMessage);
}

public class TestEmailService : ITestEmailService
{
    private readonly NetworkCredential networkCredentials;
    private readonly SmtpClientConfiguration smtpClientConfiguration;

    public TestEmailService(SmtpClientConfiguration smtpClientConfiguration)
    {
        this.smtpClientConfiguration = smtpClientConfiguration;

        networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = smtpClientConfiguration.Username,
            Password = smtpClientConfiguration.Password
        };
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        using var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = networkCredentials;
        smtpClient.Host = smtpClientConfiguration.Host;
        smtpClient.Port = smtpClientConfiguration.Port;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = smtpClientConfiguration.Ssl;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        if (mailMessage != null)
            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

Our appsettings are as follows:

```
"SmtpClientConfiguration": {
    "Username": "",
    "Password": "",
    "Host": "<our company MX record>",
    "Port": 25,
    "Ssl": true
},
```

Comment: The set of outbound IP addresses for your app changes when you perform scale down operation. If you haven’t done, you may need to update the SMTP relay configuration in your Microsoft 365 account to include the new IP address.
[When outbound IPs change](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity)

Comment: Also, Azure App Service supports two types of SSL connections: Server Name Indication (SNI) SSL Connections and IP Address SSL Connections. Free and shared service plans do not support SSL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/ip-address-change-ssl 

See: [Troubleshoot outbound SMTP connectivity problems in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

Following-up on this from the comment:

The set of outbound IP addresses for your app changes when you perform scale down operation. So, the issue could be due to IP address change. If you haven’t done, you may need to update the SMTP relay configuration in your Microsoft 365 account to include the new IP address: [When outbound IPs change](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change)

Also, Azure App Service supports two types of SSL connections: Server Name Indication (SNI) SSL Connections and IP Address SSL Connections. Free and shared service plans do not support SSL.
See: [Troubleshoot outbound SMTP connectivity problems in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity)